# The difference between lambda and KFunction in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

The following does not compile:

```
fun<T> doSomething(value: T, action: (value: T) -> String = Any::toString){
  //do something
}
```

The error is:

```
Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction1<Any, String> but (T) -> String was expected
```

Making it work is easy:

```
fun<T> doSomething(value: T, action: (t: T) -> String = {t -> t.toString()}) = action(value)
```

However, this leaves me wondering: what is the difference between lambdas and KFunctions? Why do we need both?

Also is there a simpler way to provide Any::toString as the default action?

Comment: `Any:` causing problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you obtain any function (lambda or otherwise) reference with `::`  you are using reflection. `KFunction` is Kotlin's way to to wrap around reflected functions.

As to making `Any::toString` work - there is a way but you may not like it:

```
fun <T> doSomething(value: T, action: (t: T) -> String = Any::toString as (T) -> String) { 
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason why the code does not compile has nothing to do with the difference between lambdas and KFunctions. It doesn't compile because the parameter needs to be a function of type `(T) -> String`, and `Any::toString` is a function of type `(Any) -> String`.

Comment: Sure, but replacing Any::toString with T::toString won't compile either. I can pass a lambda, but is there a simper way?

Comment: I don't think there is.

Answer (score 2):

It would have compiled if do like this:

```
fun <T> doSomething(value: T, action: (value: Any) -> String = Any::toString) {
    //do something
}
```

or

```
fun <T : Any> doSomething(value: T, action: (t: T) -> String = Any::toString) {
    // ...
}
```